# laravel 4.2 image intervention not re-sizing properly for specified height

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

I'm using laravel 4.2 image intervention in ubuntu 32 bit. It's working, but image is not resizing for the specified height. Suppose I'm trying to resize image of `width=800, height=600` to `width=250, height=250` but it is resizing to `width=250, height=188` .

I used the following code in my controller.

```
$imageType = array(
  'detail_page' => array(
  'width' => 250,
  'height' => 250      
  ),
);

$file = Input::file('album_image');

if($file->isValid()) {

    $file_name = microtime();
    $file_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace('.', '_', $file_name);
    $file_name = $file_name . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file->move(public_path() . '/album_uploads/', $file_name);

    foreach ($imageType as $key => $value) {

      $file = Image::make(sprintf('album_uploads/%s',$file_name))->resize($value['width'], $value['height'],

        function($constraint) {
          $constraint->aspectRatio();
      });

      $file->save(public_path().'/album_uploads/'.$value['width'].'X'.$value['height'].'/'. $file_name);

    }

   $album_image_url = URL::to('album_uploads/' . $file_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your aspect ratio constraint: 800x600 -> 250x188 -> 4x3

```
function($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
}
```